# Ayuda Consulta sql 1 -DISTINCT-LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, distinct

Tengo  la  siguiente  consulta:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_unidad, economico, placas, marca, modelo
FROM unidades 
LEFT JOIN disponible on disponible.id_unidad1 = unidades.id_unidad
WHERE fecha1 <> '2019-04-25';
```

Donde  la  tabla  unidad  contiene  los  campos a mostrar (en la  consulta) y la  tabla  disponible contiene los campos `id_disponible`, `fecha1` e `id_unidad1`.

Lo que busco es que el usuario ingrese una fecha1 ejemplo 2019-04-25 y el sistema  muestre  las unidades que no están asociadas con esa fecha en la tabla disponible (que no se repitan).
 existen  2  resultados  posibles   ambos   me  funcionarían
Resultado 1 
que  se  muestren los  registros  de la tabla   unidad con id_unidad 3, 4, 5 y 6 ya  que   el id_unidad = 2  esta  asociado  con la  fecha especificada.
Resultado 2
 que  se muestren los registros  de la  tabla disponible con id_unidad1 5  y 6 
 ya  que   el 2  esta  asociado  con la  fecha  especificada

[image: tabla Disponibles]

[image: Tabla tabla unidades]

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indica exactamente el resultado quieres obtener para esos datos de ejemplo. Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask]. Bienvendo a [so]

Comment: Gracias   David  por la información  ya  la  modifique espero    este  bien planteada la   pregunta  esta  vez

Comment: Mucho mejor, pero mejor sube el dataset en SQL, en imágenes es más complicado copiarlo

Answer (score 1):

Si no entendí mal tu pregunta lo que quieres son todas las unidades que no tengan un registro asociado en la tabla disponible en ese fecha lo cual se puede hacer así.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_unidad, economico, placas, marca, modelo
FROM unidades
WHERE id_unidad NOT IN 
(SELECT id_unidad1 
FROM disponible 
WHERE fecha1 <> '2019-04-03');
```

Comment: Hola  Ruben   gracias  por  tu aporte modifique  la   pregunta   para  que  se  entienda  mejor   el resultado  deseado Saludos!

Comment: Gracias. No se me da muy bien eso de las etiquetas HTML (en realidad nada que tenga que ver con diseño)

Comment: Únicamente   busco  la  consulta   que  me  de  solo esos  datos